# Navigate from a process to it's parent

Tags: c++, winapi, process

I'm stuck with the process model of IE8, where a *GetWindowThreadProcessId()* for my MFC embedded window will give me a child IE PID, as the *GetWindowThreadProcessId()* for my container page will give me the root IE PID.

Which is bad, as I want to filter my container out, while enumerating windows.

So I'm looking for a way to get the PID of the *parent* of a given process, so as to get, from my MFC app, the root IE PID.

Sysinternals' [ProcessExplorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) knows how to do that, displaying processes in treeview, so I'm sure there's a way to achieve that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you [seen this codeproject article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/ParentPID.aspx) or [this codeguru article](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/w-p/win32/article.php/c1437)?

I think the better method is in the codeguru article.

Basically you want the "ULONG InheritedFromUniqueProcessId" member of PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION.  See [NtQueryInformationProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684280(VS.85).aspx) and [this page](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfx64bit/thread/7bfc32ea-b493-4853-a690-fef7b1170162/).

Comment: Personally I prefer NtQueryInformationProcess, and link against ntdll.dll statically :)

Comment: I saw the codeproject method in MSDN and was hoping for a less complicated solution. I'll give a try to NtQueryInformationProcess, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

use ToolHelp32 functions http://support.microsoft.com/kb/192986 and sort their as tree.

But if you have embeded window, maybe your code in IE process? what type of embeding are you use, ocx or dll?

Comment: ocx, sir. I'll try the NtQueryInformationProcess way, thanks for your answer.